# Unity Game Crashing on Startup due to Admob only on Android 12 devices

Tags: android-12

Actually my game is crashing on android 12. I tried a lot but couldn't figure out. I know the actual reason is admob because when i remove admob game is working fine and I am using latest admob plugin(6.1.2) (tried other versions too) for unity 2020.3.23f1.[[image: This is the plugin folder structer][1]]

i am attaching all details here

////////////////This is the error which i am receiving on android 12////////////////////////////[image]
2022-02-06 17:08:37.561 364-438/? E/android.hardware.audio@7.0-impl.ranchu: device/generic/goldfish/audio/stream_out.cpp:updateSourceMetadata:377 failure: Result::NOT_SUPPORTED
2022-02-06 17:08:37.705 364-438/? E/android.hardware.audio@7.0-impl.ranchu: device/generic/goldfish/audio/stream_out.cpp:updateSourceMetadata:377 failure: Result::NOT_SUPPORTED
2022-02-06 17:08:37.714 1419-1419/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox E/HwDetectorWithState: a: 3
2022-02-06 17:08:37.790 414-455/? E/SurfaceFlinger: Only WindowManager is allowed to use eEarlyWakeup[Start|End] flags
2022-02-06 17:08:38.237 414-455/? E/SurfaceFlinger: Only WindowManager is allowed to use eEarlyWakeup[Start|End] flags
2022-02-06 17:08:41.657 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2022-02-06 17:08:41.657 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2022-02-06 17:08:41.657 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2022-02-06 17:08:41.658 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2022-02-06 17:08:41.658 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2022-02-06 17:08:41.659 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2022-02-06 17:08:41.659 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2022-02-06 17:08:41.659 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2022-02-06 17:08:41.659 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2022-02-06 17:08:41.660 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2022-02-06 17:08:41.661 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2022-02-06 17:08:41.662 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2022-02-06 17:08:41.662 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2022-02-06 17:08:41.662 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2022-02-06 17:08:41.662 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2022-02-06 17:08:41.663 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2022-02-06 17:08:42.413 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/EGL_emulation: [getAttribValue] Bad attribute idx
2022-02-06 17:08:42.413 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/EGL_emulation: tid 17418: eglGetConfigAttrib(1292): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
2022-02-06 17:08:43.703 364-438/? E/android.hardware.audio@7.0-impl.ranchu: device/generic/goldfish/audio/stream_out.cpp:updateSourceMetadata:377 failure: Result::NOT_SUPPORTED
2022-02-06 17:08:43.746 364-438/? E/android.hardware.audio@7.0-impl.ranchu: device/generic/goldfish/audio/stream_out.cpp:updateSourceMetadata:377 failure: Result::NOT_SUPPORTED
2022-02-06 17:08:47.672 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2022-02-06 17:08:47.673 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH: Version '2020.3.23f1 (c5d91304a876)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a'
2022-02-06 17:08:47.675 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/libc: The property "ro.build.fingerprint" has a value with length 96 that is too large for __system_property_get()/__system_property_read(); use __system_property_read_callback() instead.
2022-02-06 17:08:47.678 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH: Build fingerprint: 'Must use __system_property_read_callback() to read'
2022-02-06 17:08:47.678 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH: Revision: '0'
2022-02-06 17:08:47.679 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH: ABI: 'arm64'
2022-02-06 17:08:47.720 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH: Timestamp: 2022-02-06 17:08:47+0500
2022-02-06 17:08:47.722 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH: pid: 17395, tid: 17418, name: UnityMain  >>> com.ff.ffl <<<
2022-02-06 17:08:47.723 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH: uid: 10171
2022-02-06 17:08:47.726 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xba
2022-02-06 17:08:47.729 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH: Cause: null pointer dereference
2022-02-06 17:08:47.736 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:     x0  00000000000000a8  x1  00007019513eedb8  x2  fffffffffffffff9  x3  746573744d6f6465
2022-02-06 17:08:47.738 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:     x4  65646f4d74736574  x5  746573744d6f6465  x6  65646f4d74736574  x7  657664412e656e69
2022-02-06 17:08:47.740 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:     x8  000070194ccbf940  x9  0000000000000000  x10 0000000000000000  x11 0000000000000000
2022-02-06 17:08:47.741 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:     x12 0000701a06e74c40  x13 0000000000000020  x14 0000000000000020  x15 0000701949982a98
2022-02-06 17:08:47.742 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:     x16 000070194995e920  x17 00007019513ec7dc  x18 00007019499c4000  x19 0000000000000000
2022-02-06 17:08:47.743 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:     x20 0000000000000000  x21 000070194c071a50  x22 0000000000000001  x23 000070195448cb40
2022-02-06 17:08:47.744 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:     x24 0000000000000000  x25 00000000000000ff  x26 0000000000000000  x27 0000000000000000
2022-02-06 17:08:47.746 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:     x28 0000000000000000  x29 0000701948a32940
2022-02-06 17:08:47.746 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:     sp  0000701948a32900  lr  000070194c35212c  pc  000070194c35212c
2022-02-06 17:08:47.754 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH: backtrace:
2022-02-06 17:08:47.756 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:       #00 pc 000000000013f12c  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
2022-02-06 17:08:47.758 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:       #01 pc 0000000000694378  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: bf35a547cfa20523c2e54a857f01c06304a3d52f)
2022-02-06 17:08:47.758 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:       #02 pc 00000000002481cc  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: bf35a547cfa20523c2e54a857f01c06304a3d52f)
2022-02-06 17:08:47.759 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:       #03 pc 00000000001e7b90  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: bf35a547cfa20523c2e54a857f01c06304a3d52f)
2022-02-06 17:08:47.760 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:       #04 pc 0000000000265140  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
2022-02-06 17:08:47.760 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:       #05 pc 00000000002723fc  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
2022-02-06 17:08:47.760 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:       #06 pc 000000000027f368  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
2022-02-06 17:08:47.761 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:       #07 pc 000000000027edd4  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
2022-02-06 17:08:47.762 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:       #08 pc 00000000002c0ea4  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
2022-02-06 17:08:47.762 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:       #09 pc 00000000002c0d60  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
2022-02-06 17:08:47.762 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:       #10 pc 00000000002c0cbc  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
2022-02-06 17:08:47.763 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:       #11 pc 00000000001f5e1c  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
2022-02-06 17:08:47.763 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:       #12 pc 00000000001f60d0  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
2022-02-06 17:08:47.764 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:       #13 pc 00000000001f5b00  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
2022-02-06 17:08:47.764 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:       #14 pc 00000000001f5bc0  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
2022-02-06 17:08:47.764 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:       #15 pc 00000000001f5894  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
2022-02-06 17:08:47.765 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:       #16 pc 00000000001f67f0  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
2022-02-06 17:08:47.765 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:       #17 pc 00000000001f6e00  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
2022-02-06 17:08:47.766 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:       #18 pc 00000000002dff74  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
2022-02-06 17:08:47.766 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:       #19 pc 00000000002f560c  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
2022-02-06 17:08:47.767 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH:       #20 pc 0000000000001018  /system/lib64/arm64/libnative_bridge_vdso.so (BuildId: 7c48b60cb2ca70c8827595e62ab91096)
2022-02-06 17:08:48.204 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/CRASH: Tombstone written to: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.ff.ffl/files/tombstone_01

```
--------- beginning of crash
```

2022-02-06 17:08:48.209 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: UnityMain
Process: com.ff.ffl, PID: 17395
java.lang.Error: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Version '2020.3.23f1 (c5d91304a876)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a'
Build fingerprint: 'Must use __system_property_read_callback() to read'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2022-02-06 17:08:47+0500
pid: 17395, tid: 17418, name: UnityMain  >>> com.ff.ffl <<<
uid: 10171
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xba
Cause: null pointer dereference
x0  00000000000000a8  x1  00007019513eedb8  x2  fffffffffffffff9  x3  746573744d6f6465
x4  65646f4d74736574  x5  746573744d6f6465  x6  65646f4d74736574  x7  657664412e656e69
x8  000070194ccbf940  x9  0000000000000000  x10 0000000000000000  x11 0000000000000000
x12 0000701a06e74c40  x13 0000000000000020  x14 0000000000000020  x15 0000701949982a98
x16 000070194995e920  x17 00007019513ec7dc  x18 00007019499c4000  x19 0000000000000000
x20 0000000000000000  x21 000070194c071a50  x22 0000000000000001  x23 000070195448cb40
x24 0000000000000000  x25 00000000000000ff  x26 0000000000000000  x27 0000000000000000
x28 0000000000000000  x29 0000701948a32940
sp  0000701948a32900  lr  000070194c35212c  pc  000070194c35212c

```
backtrace:
      #00 pc 000000000013f12c  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
      #01 pc 0000000000694378  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: bf35a547cfa20523c2e54a857f01c06304a3d52f)
      #02 pc 00000000002481cc  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: bf35a547cfa20523c2e54a857f01c06304a3d52f)
      #03 pc 00000000001e7b90  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: bf35a547cfa20523c2e54a857f01c06304a3d52f)
      #04 pc 0000000000265140  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
      #05 pc 00000000002723fc  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
      #06 pc 000000000027f368  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
      #07 pc 000000000027edd4  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
      #08 pc 00000000002c0ea4  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
      #09 pc 00000000002c0d60  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
      #10 pc 00000000002c0cbc  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
      #11 pc 00000000001f5e1c  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
      #12 pc 00000000001f60d0  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
      #13 pc 00000000001f5b00  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
      #14 pc 00000000001f5bc0  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
```

2022-02-06 17:08:48.210 17395-17418/com.ff.ffl E/AndroidRuntime:       #15 pc 00000000001f5894  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
#16 pc 00000000001f67f0  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
#17 pc 00000000001f6e00  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
#18 pc 00000000002dff74  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
#19 pc 00000000002f560c  /data/app/~~hzNxIVlVTHlMOIjk1xTatg==/com.ff.ffl-uH3Er27ItfyYWlJGJ8i98A==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: c40b1dabcb8c62da7adb32bf0e3111b61bfe1dc8)
#20 pc 0000000000001018  /system/lib64/arm64/libnative_bridge_vdso.so (BuildId: 7c48b60cb2ca70c8827595e62ab91096)

```
    at libunity.0x13f12c(Native Method)
    at libil2cpp.0x694378(Native Method)
    at libil2cpp.0x2481cc(Native Method)
    at libil2cpp.0x1e7b90(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x265140(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x2723fc(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x27f368(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x27edd4(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x2c0ea4(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x2c0d60(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x2c0cbc(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x1f5e1c(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x1f60d0(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x1f5b00(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x1f5bc0(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x1f5894(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x1f67f0(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x1f6e00(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x2dff74(Native Method)
    at libunity.0x2f560c(Native Method)
    at libnative_bridge_vdso.0x1018(Native Method)
```

2022-02-06 17:08:56.286 17395-17395/com.ff.ffl E/Surface: freeAllBuffers: 1 buffers were freed while being dequeued!
2022-02-06 17:08:57.576 364-438/? E/android.hardware.audio@7.0-impl.ranchu: device/generic/goldfish/audio/stream_out.cpp:updateSourceMetadata:377 failure: Result::NOT_SUPPORTED
2022-02-06 17:08:57.682 364-438/? E/android.hardware.audio@7.0-impl.ranchu: device/generic/goldfish/audio/stream_out.cpp:updateSourceMetadata:377 failure: Result::NOT_SUPPORTED
2022-02-06 17:08:57.709 364-438/? E/android.hardware.audio@7.0-impl.ranchu: device/generic/goldfish/audio/stream_out.cpp:updateSourceMetadata:377 failure: Result::NOT_SUPPORTED
2022-02-06 17:09:04.920 1084-1991/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.wellbeing.api
2022-02-06 17:09:21.785 389-389/? E/android.hardware.power.stats@1.0-service-mock: Failed to getEnergyData
2022-02-06 17:11:21.786 389-389/? E/android.hardware.power.stats@1.0-service-mock: Failed to getEnergyData
2022-02-06 17:13:21.787 389-389/? E/android.hardware.power.stats@1.0-service-mock: Failed to getEnergyData
2022-02-06 17:15:21.787 389-389/? E/android.hardware.power.stats@1.0-service-mock: Failed to getEnergyData
2022-02-06 17:17:21.788 389-389/? E/android.hardware.power.stats@1.0-service-mock: Failed to getEnergyData
2022-02-06 17:18:56.863 1239-15573/com.google.android.gms E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2022-02-06 17:19:21.790 389-389/? E/android.hardware.power.stats@1.0-service-mock: Failed to getEnergyData
2022-02-06 17:21:21.793 389-389/? E/android.hardware.power.stats@1.0-service-mock: Failed to getEnergyData
2022-02-06 17:23:21.792 389-389/? E/android.hardware.power.stats@1.0-service-mock: Failed to getEnergyData
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

[image: This is the gradle template and gradle properties files]